# Union of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, union, intersection

I was asked an exam question:

> Write a program to read two string values, and find the intersection and union of entered string character sets. E.g.
>
> - str1: `"Hi hello"`
> - str2: `"How are you"`
> - Union: `"hielowaryu"`
> - Intersection: `"hoe"` (case insenstive)

This was a Java 101 course, so we weren't supposed to be using anything more than the absolute basics (no advanced data structures). I couldn't do it within the allotted time, but I'd like to know how to solve this.

Comment: This can be done using for loop,CharAt(), "==" etc

Comment: Well, what did you try doing?

Comment: Please share your approach and code snippet so that we can help you proceed instead of just providing a straightforward answer.  An algo would also suffice.

Comment: Which part did you have trouble with: 1) Converting a string to a set of characters, 2) computing the union of two sets, or 3) computing the intersection of two sets?

Comment: @ChrisMartin It was a written exam, so I was having trouble visualizing the code (I write labs well, but I am the worst at written tests). I had taken the two strings, and was using a single char from the first string and indexOf() to locate it in the 2nd string. If it was there I added it to a StringBuffer for intersection. I wanted to do something similar for union, but I didn't have the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolutely most basic way: loop through the first string, check for its containment in the second. It looks like your union and intersect shouldn't have duplicates (if they can this is a much harder problem).

```
/** Returns the union of the two strings, case insensitive. 
    Takes O( (|S1| + |S2|) ^2 ) time. */
public static String union(String s1, String s2){
    String s = (s1 + s2).toLowerCase(); //start with entire contents of both strings
    int i = 0;
    while(i < s.length()){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(i != s.lastIndexOf(c)) //If c occurs multiple times in s, remove first one
            s = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, s.length());
        else i++; //otherwise move pointer forward
    }
}

/** Returns the intersection of the two strings, case insensitive. 
    Takes O( |S1| * |S2| ) time. */
public static String intersect(String s1, String s2){
    String s = "";
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
    for(char c : s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        if(s2.indexOf(c) != -1 && s.indexOf(c) == -1)
            s += c;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. How does chaining methods work in the intersect method? Does s1 get lowercased and then toCharArray? Or do char[] have a lowercase method? Just asking, don't know much.

Comment: Your first instinct was correct - the `lowerCase()` method returns a new string composed of lower case versions of the characters in the original string. So if `s1 = "HeLlo"`, `s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()` is `"HeLlo" -> "hello" -> {'h','e','l','l','o'}`